# Invoking generic type

Tags: java, variables, generics

I am currently following the examples on Java's Generics on the following page:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

```
public interface Pair<K, V> {
    public K getKey();
    public V getValue();
}

public class OrderedPair<K, V> implements Pair<K, V> {

    private K key;
    private V value;

    public OrderedPair(K key, V value) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
    }

    public K getKey()   { return key; }
    public V getValue() { return value; }
}


Pair<String, Integer> p1 = new OrderedPair<String, Integer>("Even", 8);
OrderedPair<String, Integer> p1 = new OrderedPair<>("Even", 8);
```

My question is about the lines at the end which create variables.  At the very start, one starts with the pair interface, while another starts with the OrderedPair class.  Is there a difference whether which one is used?  I'm just trying to understand why the code is different.

Comment: The `<>` syntax does type inference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#type-inference-instantiation (If that's what you're asking. It's not really clear what difference you mean.)

Answer (score 2):

The code is not valid.  Java does not allow two variables of the same name in the same scope.

If names were `p1` and `p2`, each of them references a different object of class `OrderedPair<String,Integer>`.  In the second case you were able to omit the generic arguments from the `new` because they were already specified with the type of the variable (`OrderedPair<String, Integer>` before the variable name).  In the first case the type of the object is a subclass of the type of the variable.  This is valid per polymorphism.  The generic arguments were specified twice, which is also valid though redundant.

As said above, both `p1` and `p2` reference objects of type `OrderedPair<String,Integer>`. However, `p1` and `p2` have different **static** (declared) types.  In this case, this means that:

1. If type `OrderedPair` had a method `reverseOrder` (just to say something) not inherited from `Pair`, then `p1.reverseOrder()` would not be valid (even if the referenced object is of the correct type, but the compiler doesn't know this), but `p2.reverseOrder()` would be.  Here, `p2` "is better" than `p1` (because you required more specificity and `p2` has it).
2. If you defined a third type `UnorderedPait implements Pair`, new instances of this type could be assigned to `p1`, but not to `p2`.  Here, `p1` "is better" than `p2` (because you required more generality and `p1` has it).

Comment: @millimoose  So I thought milliseconds before seeing your comment.

Comment: Aaanyway. "This is valid per polymorphism, but forces you to specify generic arguments twice." is incorrect, despite the OP's code making it seem like that's the case. `List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();` works for instance. (In fact, even more complicated cases do: http://ideone.com/EWKpsw.)

Comment: @millimoose  Corrections done.  Thanks for your attentive eye.

Answer (score 0):

The first one uses a reference of Pair. With this you can point to any implementation of Pair interface - OrderedPair, SortedPair, LongPair etc.

But with the second reference, you can only point to an object of OrderedPair

Answer (score 0):

If there were methods in the `OrderedPair` class that weren't listed in the `Pair` interface, then you'd need an expression of type `OrderedPair` in order to call them.  In other words, you'd want to declare your variable as an `OrderedPair`, then call the methods on that variable.  On the other hand, if you're only using methods that are listed in the `Pair` interface, then you can declare your variable as a `Pair`, and call the methods on it.  There are two reasons that you might want to do the latter.

- A variable of type `Pair` can reference objects of other classes that implement `Pair` - you might have `UnorderedPair`, `PrettyPair` and so on, that are not subclasses of `OrderedPair`.
- It tells future maintainers of your program that you are only using the `Pair` methods of that variable - that any methods that are specific to `OrderedPair` won't be used.